# Value (price) of defaultable zero coupon bond with credit risk involved

Tags: stochastic-processes, risk-neutral-measure, credit-derivatives

I'm trying to derivate the Value (price) of defaultable zero coupon bond, but there some steps (math) in between I can't figure out.

From the default process modelling, we have:

$$P(t ≤ \tau < t+dt | \tau > t ) ≈ h_tdt$$

and:

$$P( \tau > t ) = \exp\left(-\int_0^t h_s ds\right) $$

Hence combining both, the unconditional probability:

$$P(t ≤ \tau < t+dt ) = h_t\exp\left(-\int_0^t h_s ds\right)dt$$

Next proceed with the derivation of the value of a defaultable bond

\begin{align}
&B(0,T) \\
=&  \color{fuchsia}{\text{EV[non-default scenario]}} + \color{blue}{\text{EV[default scenario]}}  \\
=& E\left[\color{fuchsia}{\exp\left(-\int_0^T r_t dt\right)·\mathbf{1}_{\{T<\tau\}}} + \color{blue}{\int_0^T RR · \exp\left(-\int_0^t r_s ds\right) · P(t ≤ \tau < t+dt )} \right]\\
=& E\left[\color{fuchsia}{\exp\left(-\int_0^T r_t dt\right)·\exp\left(-\int_0^T h_t dt\right)} + \color{blue}{\int_0^T RR · \exp\left(-\int_0^t r_s ds\right) · h_t\exp\left(-\int_0^t h_s ds\right)dt} \right] \\
=& E\left[\color{fuchsia}{\exp\left(-\int_0^T (r_t+h_t) dt\right)} + \color{blue}{\int_0^T RR · h_t· \exp\left(-\int_0^\color{red}{t} (r_s+h_s) ds\right) \color{red}{dt}} \right]
\end{align}

I have derived up to here and come to the problem that I do not know how to integrate the blue part, with the  upper bound of the inner integral as the integration variable of the outer integral (which I have colored red for clarity).

---

The textbook do provide the final result as the following, but i'm not sure how those are derived from my steps above
[image]

Comment: hint given is using the approximation: e^x = 1 + x

Comment: @Gordon I dont quite get the your simplification from step 1 to 2, why would the inner integral just disappear?

Comment: @Jeremy Which textbook/chapter is this from?

Comment: You are using a different definition of the recovery rate from that given in the solution. You are assuming a constant recovery with respect to the value of the bond at any time while the solution assume a recovery proportional to the bond value at the time of the default.

Comment: @Gordon: Your ad hoc derivation is not really right, is it? You are making the same recovery assumption as that of OP rather than that of the solution. You are assuming a constant recovery with respect to the value of the bond at any time while the solution assumes a recovery proportional to the bond value at the time of the default. You are not going to get the desired solution.

Comment: @Jeremy: You should have accepted and awarded the bounty to Gordon's answer. That is a fine and correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few recovery mechanisms, for example, *recovery of par* (i.e., the notional), *recovery of treasury* (i.e., the recovery value is a constant fraction of the equivalent default-free bond), and *recovery of market value* (i.e., a fraction of its pre-default market value). Here, your formula, which is also called the [Lando formula](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691089299), assumes the recovery of market value mechanism.

Let $V_t$ be the pre-default value at time $t$ of the zero-coupon bond with maturity $T$ and unit face value (note that $V_T=1$). Moreover, let $R$ be the recovery rate, of the pre-default value $V_{\tau}$. Furthermore, let $\tau$ be the default time, $H_t=\pmb{1}_{\{\tau \leq t\}}$. Let $\mathscr{F}_t$ be the market information set at time $t$ (which roughly speaking includes all information other than the fact of default or survival). Moreover, let $\mathscr{H}_t = \sigma(H_u,\, u \leq t)$ and $\mathscr{G}_t = \mathscr{F}_t \vee \mathscr{H}_t$ be the enlarged information set. Here, we can assume that the default time $\tau$ is defined as the first jump time of an in-homogeneous Poisson process, where the intensity process $\{h_t,\, t \ge 0\}$ is deterministic, or a Cox process, where the intensity is stochastic (see [Bielecki and Rutkowski](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540675930) for more details).

Generally, we assume that the $\mathscr{H}$-condition is satisfied, that is, $\mathscr{H}_t$ and $\mathscr{F}_{\infty}$ are independent conditioned on $\mathscr{F}_t$; in other words, for any $\mathscr{H}_t$-measurable random variable $X$ and $\mathscr{F}_{\infty}$ measurable random variable $Y$,
\begin{align*}
E(XY\,|\,\mathscr{F}_t) = E(X\,|\,\mathscr{F}_t)E(Y\,|\,\mathscr{F}_t).
\end{align*}

The other key formula to use is the *filtration switching formula* (see the book [Interest Rate Models - Theory and Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540221492)): For any $\mathscr{G}_{\infty}$ measurable random variable $Y$,
\begin{align*}
E\left(\pmb{1}_{\{\tau > t\}}Y\,|\,\mathscr{G}_t\right) = \pmb{1}_{\{\tau > t\}}\frac{E\left(\pmb{1}_{\{\tau > t\}}Y\,|\,\mathscr{F}_t\right)}{E\left(\pmb{1}_{\{\tau > t\}}\,|\,\mathscr{F}_t\right)}.\tag 1
\end{align*}

Then, for $0 \leq t < T$,
\begin{align*}
\pmb{1}_{\{\tau > t\}}V_{t} &= E\bigg(\pmb{1}_{\{\tau > T\}}e^{-\int_{t}^{T} r_s ds} + \pmb{1}_{\{t< \tau \le T\}}  R\, V_{\tau}e^{-\int_{t}^{\tau} r_s ds} \, \big|\, \mathscr{G}_{t}\bigg) \\
&=\pmb{1}_{\{\tau > t\}} E\bigg(e^{-\int_{t}^{T} (r_s+h_s) ds} + \int_{t}^{T}R\, V_{u}h_u e^{-\int_{t}^{u} (r_s+h_s) ds} du \, \big|\, \mathscr{F}_{t}\bigg) \tag 2 \\
&=\pmb{1}_{\{\tau > t\}} e^{\int_0^{t} (r_s+h_s) ds} E\bigg(e^{-\int_0^{T} (r_s+h_s) ds} + \int_{t}^{T}R\, V_{u} h_u e^{-\int_0^{u} (r_s+h_s) ds} du \, \big|\, \mathscr{F}_{t}\bigg). \nonumber
\end{align*}
Here, the $\mathscr{H}$-condition and the *filtration switching formula* are employed in the derivation of $(2)$.

Let
\begin{align*}
M_t = E\bigg(e^{-\int_0^{T} (r_s+h_s) ds} + \int_0^{T}R\, V_{u}h_u e^{-\int_0^{u} (r_s+h_s) ds} du \, \big|\, \mathscr{F}_t\bigg).
\end{align*}
Then, $M_t$ is a martingale. Moreover,
\begin{align*}
V_t = e^{\int_0^t (r_s+h_s) ds}\bigg(M_t - \int_0^{t} R\,V_{u}h_u e^{-\int_0^{u} (r_s+h_s) ds} du \bigg).
\end{align*}
By Ito's lemma,
\begin{align*}
d\Big(e^{-\int_0^t (r_s+(1-R)h_s) ds} V_t \Big) = e^{\int_0^t R\, h_s ds} dM_t.
\end{align*}
Since $M_t$ is a martingale, $e^{-\int_0^t (r_s+(1-R)h_s) ds} V_t$ is also a martingale over $[0, T]$. Then, for any $0\le t \le u\le T$,
\begin{align*}
e^{-\int_0^t (r_s+(1-R)h_s) ds} V_t = E\Big(e^{-\int_0^u (r_s+(1-R)h_s) ds} V_u \, \big|\, \mathscr{F}_t \Big).
\end{align*}
In particular,
\begin{align*}
V_0 = E\left(e^{-\int_0^{T} (r_s+(1-R)h_s) ds}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: +1. This is a very nice answer. I wonder why the OP did not award his bounty to it.

Comment: Great answers as always @Gordon.

Comment: Thanks @DeepInTheQF.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for me to understand exactly what you are asking, but I will try to answer. If my answer misses the mark please clarify exactly it is what you don't understand and I will try again.

We have
\begin{aligned}
    P(\tau \leq t + dt \vert \tau > t) &= \frac{P(t < \tau \leq t+dt)}{P(\tau > t)} \\
        &= 1 - \exp \bigg(\int_t^{t+dt} h_u du \bigg) \\
        &\approx h_tdt
\end{aligned}

Where the approxomation comes from Taylor expansion of $e$ (the hint provided).

Furthermore (from the definition of the hazard rate),
$$ P(\tau > t) = \exp\bigg( -\int_0^t h_u du \bigg) $$

Is that enough? Maybe you can work it out from here.

Comment: Hi Rayl, I've updated my question entirely and added in more steps and color for clarity. The 2 equation you've provided are just the early steps which i've incorporated them in my derivation. Can u help to take a look again see if you can help?