# conditional expectation formula of default in CVA

Tags: credit, cva

Here is the formula of CVA in page 74 in book `Modern Derivatives Pricing and Credit Exposure Analysis`.

[image]

Here $t_0 = t<t_1<\cdots<t_n = T;$ $\tau$ is the default; $X(t)$ is any value.

I don't much understand how we get the second equation:
$$E^Q[\mathbb{1}_{\tau>t_i}X(t_{i-1})|\mathcal{F}_t] = E^Q\Big[E^Q[\mathbb{1}_{\tau>t_i}]X(t_{i-1})|\mathcal{F}_t\Big]$$
It hints that

> This is possible for the expectations containing $X(t_i)$ and $X(t_{i−1})$ since these are both $\mathcal{F}(t_i)$-measurable; apply the tower law of conditional expectations.

Does that mean
$$E^Q[\mathbb{1}_{\tau>t_i}X(t_{i-1})|\mathcal{F}_t] = E^Q\Big[E^Q[\mathbb{1}_{\tau>t_i}X(t_{i-1})|\mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]|\mathcal{F}_t\Big]=E^Q\Big[E^Q[\mathbb{1}_{\tau>t_i}|\mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]X(t_{i-1})|\mathcal{F}_t\Big].$$

But how to convert $E^Q[\mathbb{1}_{\tau>t_i}|\mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]$ to $E^Q[\mathbb{1}_{\tau>t_i}]?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, for any $u > 0$,
\begin{align*}
E^Q(1_{\tau > u} \mid \mathscr{F}_u) = e^{-\int_0^u \lambda(s)ds}.
\end{align*}
For example, given $\lambda$, we can define the default time $\tau$ as
\begin{align*}
\tau = \inf\left\{t \in \mathbb{R}_+: e^{-\int_0^t \lambda_s ds} \le \xi \right\}, 
\end{align*}
where $\xi$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_{\infty}$ and is uniformly distributed over $(0, 1)$.

Then
\begin{align*}
E^Q\left(1_{\tau>t_i} X(t_{i-1}) \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right) &= E^Q\left(X(t_{i-1})E^Q(1_{\tau>t_i} \mid \mathscr{F}_{t_i}\big) \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right)\\
&=E^Q\left(X(t_{i-1}) e^{-\int_0^{t_i} \lambda(s)ds} \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right).
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
E^Q\left(1_{\tau>t_i} X(t_i) \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right) &= E^Q\left(X(t_i)E^Q(1_{\tau>t_i} \mid \mathscr{F}_{t_i}\big) \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right)\\
&=E^Q\left(X(t_i) e^{-\int_0^{t_i} \lambda(s)ds} \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right).
\end{align*}

Comment: could you explain more on why \begin{align*}
E^Q(1_{\tau > u} \mid \mathscr{F}_u) = e^{-\int_0^u \lambda(s)ds}.
\end{align*} Since $1_{\tau > u}$ is $\mathscr{F}_u$-measurable, i think it should be $E^Q(1_{\tau > u} \mid \mathscr{F}_u) = 1_{\tau > u}.$ Namely at time $t_i,$ we already know whether the default has happened.

Comment: Note that $\xi$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_{\infty}$. From my definition of the default time, $1_{\tau>u}$ is not $\mathscr{F}_u$ measurable. See also [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55090/value-price-of-defaultable-zero-coupon-bond-with-credit-risk-involved/55157#55157) for further discussions.

Comment: ok, get your point, it is already the result after the filtering switch formula. Then $1_{\tau>u}$ is actually independent on $\mathcal{F}_t$ for any $t.$

Comment: That is true if $\lambda$ is deterministic. In general, $\lambda$ can be a process adapted to $\{\mathscr{F}_t\}$, that is, for any $t>0$, $\lambda_t$ is $\mathscr{F}_t$ measurable.